# Can a DC motor safely exert torque opposite its direction of rotation?

Tags: motor, power-electronics, dc-motor, electro-mechanical

I have a shaft that will turn in direction A.

I want it to continue turning in direction A.

I want a motor (preferably DC) to exert torque opposite direction A.

Throughout most of its life, the motor will oppose whatever direction its shaft is turning.

Is this a thing that most DC motors can do?

It seems to me to be the sort of thing you might want for the inverted pendulum problem, and I know people build inverted pendula, but I don't know much more than that.

I took control theory 20 years ago and haven't used it since. I know linear motors are a nice theoretical device, but given how nonlinear inductors are, I'm not comfortable assuming that real motors behave like this.

Is the life of the motor typically shortened by using it this way?

If so, is there a kind of motor that can safely do this?

Comment: An electrical machine will be acting as a generator: You will have to cope with the energy converted from mechanical to electrical.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque_motor

Comment: That's called braking and yes, braking can be done safely.

Answer (score 3):

> *is there a kind of motor that can safely do this*

It's called a generator and load resistor. Maybe you can replace the load resistor with a more sophisticated circuit that can reclaim this energy instead of burning it. Think what electric cars do when braking; they recharge their battery.

Comment: Hi, Andy. Is that not just electric braking? And it would decrease with speed. I work with film unwinders and rewinders and the unwinders would generally be set up to run in the "wind" direction to keep the required tension on the film - often with feedback from a potentiometer on a dancer arm.

Comment: @Transistor yes it is; have I misread the question in some way maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a powering a DC motor to apply torque against the shaft's running direction, you could consider a DC motor, physically driven by the shaft, to be a generator, creating an EMF proportional to the shaft's angular velocity.

If you do nothing with that EMF, not using it it to push current through anything, to "do work", then the motor offers no resistance to the shaft's rotation (other than its own friction), there's no opposing torque, no energy is removed from the shaft.

But, you *can* do work with that EMF, which will result in torque that the shaft must overcome, and any work it does in doing so is ultimately work done by the shaft's *own* source of energy. This is a simple consequence of conservation of energy. If the shaft experiences a torque opposing its rotation, then the work done by the shaft each second (joules per second, which is power, in watts) is the product of that torque \$\tau\$ (Nm) and the angular velocity \$\alpha\$ (radians/s):

$$ P = \tau \alpha $$

In other words, the power in watts that the shaft is delivering to a physical load of a certain torque is calculable.

Now let's say you connect a motor to the shaft, and the shaft has angular velocity \$\alpha\$. If the motor generates a potential difference of 10V when a resistive load \$R\$ is connected across it, then the power delivered electrically to that load is:

$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} $$

If that motor were 100% efficient, with no friction, no eddy currents or winding resistance, then by conservation of energy you could equate the power delivered electrically to the load, and the power delivered mechanically by the shaft:

$$ \frac{V^2}{R} = \tau \alpha $$

It's obviously not going to be 100% efficient, and some energy will be dissipated as heat in the resistance of the motor's windings, some will be lost in overcoming friction, and so on. But you could conduct experiments to measure the efficiency of the motor at certain angular velocities, currents and voltages to obtain a figure for efficiency \$K\$, and modify the equation to be:

$$ \frac{V^2}{R} = K\tau \alpha $$

None of this requires any active circuitry, or even a power supply, just a motor and a resistor, and equipment to measure motor current and voltage. Ultimately, by choosing \$R\$, you can control torque.

However, \$R\$ is getting hot from all the \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$ power it's receiving, so you may need to take measures to cool it. The motor's winding resistance will be dissipating power too, make sure it's able to handle the currents that it's pushing through \$R\$.

Comment: Hi, Simon. See my comment to Andy's answer.